# C# write image to TCP socket

Tags: c#

I have the following code that saves an image from a camera to disk:

```
public static Image getAndSaveImage(int imageCount)
{
    var image = _camera.GetImage() as ThermalImage;
    image.Palette = PaletteManager.Iron;
    _camera.GetImage().EnterLock();
    Image camImage = _camera.GetImage().Image;
    _camera.GetImage().ExitLock();
    camImage.Save("./images/picture" + Convert.ToString(imageCount) + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    return camImage;
}
```

As you see, I am saving the image to a file. Currently, this method is called within a loop. I want to replace the saving to disk with a websocket, so clients can connect to this socket and receive bitmap images from the underlying stream. Since a bitmap is an array, this should work, shouldn't it?
I read at some documentations that I can use the `TcpListener` class.
So I would do the following:

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80);

server.Start();
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
```

How can I write my bitmap image into this stream so a python client on the other 
side
 can fetch the images? Do I need to handle the TCP handshakes on my own?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: originally, the question asked about WebSocket specifically; everything below is predicated on that - now removed - position.

WebSocket, RFC6455, is not a naked socket - it is a non-trivial frame-based protocol that starts off similarly to HTTP 1.1 before transitioning to a different protocol. So; if you want to use WebSocket, you would *probably* want to use a web-socket server implementation - doing it by hand is **not** fun (trust me, I know).

If you want simple, ASP.NET (including ASP.NET Core and Kestrel) has an inbuilt WebSocket API, trivially googlable.

However! Because it is a frame-based protocol, you won't be using a regular `Stream`. WebSocket has 2 main data frame types: text and binary (if we ignore the early prototypes of WebSocket that only had text, and was fundamentally a different protocol that shaded a name)  - in your case you'll want binary, obviously, and your best bet is probably to change your *existing* code to save to a `MemoryStream`, then get the buffer from the `MemoryStream` to pass to the WebSocket API. The *simplest* approach there is `ToArray()` on the `MemoryStream`, but the more *efficient* approach is to use `GetBuffer()` or `TryGetBuffer()`, and use an API that accepts an oversized buffer with offset (usually 0) and length (which will be `(int)memoryStream.Length`).

If you don't actually mean WebSocket, but you just mean "a TCP socket, accessed over the internet", then ignore everything I've said; `TcpListener` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am actually a Java developer and need to use C# for this specifc camera. the goal is to provide the images over a stream o a python client can fetch the images. But yout answer was very useful for clarification:)

Comment: @ItFreak btw, a few years ago I wrote a custom web-socket client/server implementation for Stack Overflow, which we called NetGain - it is [available here](https://github.com/StackExchange/NetGain) - however, in the last few months, we have switched over to a Kestrel/libuv based web-socket server in .NET Core

Comment: @ItFreak there's a huge difference between "a stream" and "WebSocket"; if you don't actually need WebSocket, I would say: don't - just use TCP. Usually, when we're talking WebSocket, we're talking about browser clients.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will just use TCP now

Comment: @ItFreak k; as a side note, though; IIRC many image encoders need to "seek" the stream, which `NetworkStream` *does not allow*; in that case, you might again want to use `MemoryStream` as the original storage to call `.Save(...)` with, then just rewind your stream (`memoryStream.Position = 0;`) and copy the contents from the `MemoryStream` to the `NetworkStream` - `memoryStream.CopyTo(networkStream)`